# How to get desired result by combining two CTE's with different tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two CTE's,firstly

```
  ;WITH CTE AS (SELECT A.* 
                    , Row_NUMBER() Over (Partition by ID order by Date asc) RN 
             FROM TABLE A)
    SELECT Sum(Weight) as IN_WT
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE RN = 1 and name='dev1'
```

and then

```
 ;WITH CTE AS (SELECT B.* 
                    , Row_NUMBER() Over (Partition by ID order by Date desc) RN1 
             FROM TABLE B)
    SELECT Sum(Weight) AS out_wt
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE RN1 = 1 and name='dev1'
```

Here we had two tablesTableA,TableB.We are getting In_wt from TableA and Out_wt from TableB.Now I had a requiremnt that the output should be combined and get in_wt,out_wt in single row from different tables and same name.I tried combining both the CTE's but didn't get the desired result.How can we do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get desired result by combining two CTE's?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753515/how-to-get-desired-result-by-combining-two-ctes)

Comment: That's a duplicate of your previous question. Don't post the same question if you don't like the answers. Either *fix* the existing question or *delete it*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ;WITH CTE1 AS (
     SELECT name, 
            Row_NUMBER() Over (Partition by ID order by Date asc) RN 
     FROM TABLEA
 ), CTE2 AS (
     SELECT name, 
            Row_NUMBER() Over (Partition by ID order by Date desc) RN
     FROM TABLEB
 )
 SELECT (SELECT Sum(Weight) FROM CTE1 WHERE RN = 1 and name='dev1') AS IN_WT,
        (SELECT Sum(Weight) FROM CTE2 WHERE RN = 1 and name='dev1') AS OUT_WT
```

Comment: First, that's a duplicate of the OP's previous query. Second, this SQL statement is essentially two separate queries. Its performance will be the same as executing two different queries. It would probably be cleaner to use two subqueries or place the `name` filter in the CTEs. This would probably be faster